# Clear a Product Collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection

Tags: magento2, product

I have a widget that shows a few products on a category page. This works if there is one instance of the widget however if i have a second widget the filters seem to reapply to the existing collection leaving no products in every instance after the first.

```
public function getProducts() {
    //print_r(get_class_methods($this->_productCollection));
    $this->_productCollection->clear();
    $productcollection = $this->_productCollection
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter($this->getAttributeFilter(), $this->getAttributeValue())
        ->addCategoriesFilter(['eq' => $this->_registry->registry('current_category')->getId()])
        ->setPageSize($this->getProductLimit())
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->load();

    return $productcollection;
}
```

I have attempted to clear with `$this->_productCollection->clear();` however still I have empty collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reusing the same productColletion and trying to clear this instance. You can create a new collection with the `CollectionFactory`:

In your __construct use:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
} {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}
```

Then **create** a new collection for each widget:

```
$collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
// Etc
```